# overriding a default template

Tags: template

hello i am trying to override the default book.phtml file with my own for a module the costumer.xml code for this is

```
<customer_address_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Address Book</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_book" name="address_book" template="customer/address/book.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_address_index>
```

in my modules .xml file i placed

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_address_index translate="label">
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>[module]/customer/address/book.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_index>

</layout>
```

what is my error?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a different template for a children block why don't reference the child block  directly and call the action method?

```
<customer_address_index>
    <reference name="address_book">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>YOUR_NEW_TEMPLATE_PATH</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_index>
```